# git push not working on a bitbucket repository

Tags: bitbucket, git-push

I've just created a repository on my Bitbucket account. I have a code already written in my laptop.
Here's the command I executed on my terminal:

```
git init
git add --all
git commit -m 'Initial commit'
git remote add origin https://<repo_owner_name>@bitbucket.org/<teamname>/<reponame>.git
git push origin master
```

I got the following error:

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://bitbucket.org/EtienneVergne/disney-app-proposal.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
```

I've tried several git pull as suggested in the message with no sucess.

Can somebody help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the remote repo and your local repo are not in sync.

*See what the error logs hints*

Do this:

```
git pull origin master
git push origin master
```

or
`git push -f origin master` to override remote changes.

Comment: The line (git push -f origin master) works ! Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: @EtienneVergne Please approve the answer for others as well. You're welcome : )